# Nestjs/Prisma not saving date number correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

When I  console log the response body right before I save it to the database, my response body shape looks correct. See below

```
//console.log response body

CreateOpenHourDto {
day: 'WEDNESDAY',
startTime: 1663858800000,
endTime: 1663878600000,
calendarId: 1
}
```

However, whenever I  go into prisma studio and check the new db entry, the startTime, endTime is differnt.

[image]

There is nothing I  have done to transform the data. Any tips are appreciated.

I  am using
nestjs, prisma, postgres sql

Answer (score 1):

My prisma model listed start and end times as "int" types and it should have been BigInt. For anyone that plans on using bigint. Be aware

Prisma returns records as plain JavaScript objects. If you attempt to use `JSON.stringify` on an object that includes a `BigInt` field, you will see the following error:

Do not know how to serialize a `BigInt`
To work around this issue, use a customized implementation of `JSON.stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify(
  this,
  (key, value) => (typeof value === 'bigint' ? value.toString() : value) // return everything else unchanged
)
```

This sounds hacky but its coming straight form the documentation as of the time of this comment.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields#working-with-bigint